# Like function in SQL Server returned all values from the table if it null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve data from the database using the `like` operator. The problem is that if the inner query returns null/empty then the outer query retrieve all values from the table.

```
SELECT customer_ref AS customer_Ref, pname AS company_name 
FROM BSD_Main_Evamp_JBW t 
WHERE  t.pname LIKE CONCAT( '%', (SELECT TOP 1 pname 
                                  FROM BSD_Main_Evamp_JBW 
                                  WHERE customer_ref = '1-31898332401005'
                                 ), '%' 
                          )
```

This kind of query work perfectly in MySQL means if inner query return null then outer query also return null.

I tried `isnull` function also with this query, but issue not resolved. How can I fix this query for SQL Server so if the inner part returns null then the outer part also returns null.

Comment: `CONCAT` replaces `NULL` with `''` (empty string). So you end up with `LIKE '%%'`, which will be most/all rows. You can try to use `+` instead; it will not replace `NULL`: `LIKE NULL` will not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCAT()` will return `%%` if sub-query return `null` value,  try to add  `+` :

```
. . .
WHERE t.pname LIKE '%' + <subquery here> + '%'
```

However, you can use variable instead of sub-query :

```
DECLARE @pname VARCHAR(255)

SELECT TOP (1) @pname = pname
FROM BSD_Main_Evamp_JBW 
WHERE customer_ref = '1-31898332401005'

SELECT . . 
FROM BSD_Main_Evamp_JBW t
WHERE (@pname IS NOT NULL AND t.pname LIKE '%' + @pname + '%');
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I think the more elegant solution is to move the `concat()` to the subquery:

```
WHERE t.pname LIKE (SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT('%', pname, '%') 
                    FROM BSD_Main_Evamp_JBW 
                    WHERE customer_ref = '1-31898332401005'
                   )
```

`CONCAT()` is a convenient function, because it will convert numbers to strings.  `+` will return an error if `pname` is not a string.

The problem with your code is that `CONCAT()` is `NULL`-friendly.  That is, it ignores `NULL` arguments rather than returning `NULL`.

With this version, the subquery still returns `NULL` if there is no match.  However, there is no `CONCAT()` to turn this into a valid string, so the `LIKE` does not return true.